# Filter for NULL in list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, null

why does filter for `NULL` in subqueries does not work?
I hoped to get the correct result by add `NULL` to the list of allowed values, for example:

```
SELECT     ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew, RMA.IdRMA
FROM         ERP_ServiceProcess RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      RMA ON ERP_ServiceProcess.fiRMA = RMA.IdRMA
WHERE  (ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew IN (NULL, 1, 7, 8))
order by ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew
```

This gives the incorrect result because all records in RMA that have no records in sub-table ERP_ServiceProcess(where ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew IS `NULL`) are dropped.

I must use this (slow) query to get the correct result:

```
SELECT     ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew, RMA.IdRMA
FROM         ERP_ServiceProcess RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      RMA ON ERP_ServiceProcess.fiRMA = RMA.IdRMA
WHERE     (ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew IS NULL)
OR (ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew IN (1, 7, 8))
order by ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew
```

Why do i have to use the second, slow query although i used `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and i've added `NULL` to the subquery?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try your first query with `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`?

Comment: @Adriy M: Yes i did. It returned the "wrong" result(dropped the NULLs).

Comment: @Tim: You mean, it omits rows with NULLs irregardless of ANSI_NULLS setting?

Comment: NULL doesn't work in a list because it isn't a value to check, it is the absence of a value.

Comment: @Tim by default ANSI_NULLS is OFF, which means comparisons with NULLs won't work, and you can only use IS/IS NOT against NULLs. If you SET ANSI_NULLS ON, comparisons will (or rather should) work.

Comment: @Andriy M - You have it the wrong way around. By default `ANSI_NULLS` are `ON` which means `IF NULL=NULL PRINT 'Y'` prints nothing. But the OP should not `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` to get this to work. That instantly makes the query unsargable and this setting is deprecated.

Comment: @Andriy: it seems that ANSI_NULLS ON is default in my database. At least when i create an UDF in SQL-Server 2005. Edit: as Martin clarified.

Comment: @Tim, @Martin: I stand corrected, sorry guys. I myself have never dealt with changing this setting. And while NULLs having always behaved according to the standards, I wasn't aware which ANSI_NULLS setting it was actually. My mistake comes from my poor reading of the doc. Will pay more attention next time. Sorry again.

Comment: So, just to clarify things, here's a passage from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx): `The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver and SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider for SQL Server automatically set ANSI_NULLS to ON when connecting. [snip] The default for SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF.` And it's this dubious last sentence about the default that misled me. That and the fact I foolishly missed the part about clients setting it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as you expect as it gets expanded to a bunch of equals operations

`fiStatusNew = NULL OR fiStatusNew = 1 OR fiStatusNew = 7 OR fiStatusNew = 8`

and `anything = NULL` is unknown.

Given this expansion there's no particular reason to think that adding an additional `OR` using `IS NULL` would make things slower on its own (the additional predicate might change the query plan to use a different access path if the statistics lead it to belive that the number of matching rows warrants this though)

You see the same behaviour in the `CASE` operation

```
SELECT CASE NULL WHEN NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END /*Returns "No"*/
```

This is one reason why you should take particular care with the inverse operation `NOT IN`. If the list contains any `NULL` values you will always get an empty result set.

`fiStatusNew NOT IN (NULL, 1,2)`

Would expand to

`fiStatusNew<> NULL and fiStatusNew<> 1 and fiStatusNew<> 2`

or

`Unknown And True/False/Unknown And True/False/Unknown`

Which always evaluates to `Unknown` under [three valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/).

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using

```
ISNULL(ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew,0) IN (0, 1, 7, 8)
```

Untested but might be quicker than the 2nd query.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Yes, i could do this. But at first view it seems to be not faster than my second query although it seems to be. First query: <1 second, second(and yours): >4seconds.

Comment: @Tim - This query is not sargable. It can not be satisfied by an index. If you have an index on `fiStatusNew` your query *will* be faster.

Comment: @martin: first i had to search for `sargable`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable
Thanks for the advice. `fiStatusNew` already was a foreignkey and creating an index on this column does'nt change the performance for neither my second query nor Fermin's query.

Comment: @Tim - Also because it is not sargable it means that its cardinality estimates of number of rows returned will not be accurate. Even without any indexes in play this might cause it to choose a sub optimal plan (for example reversing the inner and outer tables in the join operation)

Answer (score 0):

'ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew IN (NULL)' evaluates to 'ERP_ServiceProcess.fiStatusNew = NULL' and that always is false. NULL is defined in sql server as 'unknown', not as 'no value'. That's why NULL = NULL or NULL = @var (*) always evaluates to false. If you have two unknowns, you cannot check if they are equal. Only 'is NULL' works.

(*) Well, for sql server, you can set [ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)  to off but that's not really recommended as it is not standard sql behaviour.